# Prevent empty values in an array being inserted into Mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework

I am trying to prevent empty values being inserted into my *mongoDB collection*. The field in question looks like this:

**MongoDB Field**

```
   "stadiumArr" : [
     "Old Trafford",
     "El Calderon",
     ...
   ]
```

**Sample of (mapped) case class**

```
   case class FormData(_id: Option[BSONObjectID], stadiumArr: Option[List[String]], ..)
```

**Sample of Scala form**

```
  object MyForm {

     val form = Form(
        mapping(
          "_id" -> ignored(Option.empty[BSONObjectID]),
          "stadiumArr" -> optional(list(text)),
          ...
        )(FormData.apply)(FormData.unapply)
     )

  }
```

I am also using the [*Repeated Values* functionality in Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaForms#repeated-values) like so:

**Play Template**

```
   @import helper._
   @(myForm: Form[models.db.FormData])(implicit request: RequestHeader, messagesProvider: MessagesProvider)

   @repeatWithIndex(myForm("stadiumArr"), min = 5) { (stadium, idx) =>
       @inputText(stadium, '_label -> ("stadium #" + (idx + 1)))
   }
```

This ensures that whether there are at least 5 values or not in the *array*; there will still be (at least) 5 input boxes created. However if one (or more) of the input boxes are empty when the form is submitted an empty string is still being added as value in the array, e.g.

```
   "stadiumArr" : [
     "Old Trafford",
     "El Calderon",
     "",
     "",
     ""
   ]
```

Based on some other ways of converting types from/to the database; I've tried playing around with a few solutions; such as:

```
implicit val arrayWrite: Writes[List[String]] = new Writes[List[String]] {
  def writes(list: List[String]): JsValue = Json.arr(list.filterNot(_.isEmpty))
}
```

.. but this isn't working. Any ideas on how to prevent empty values being inserted into the database collection?

Comment: "but this isn't working" ... meaning? error? Defining a `Writes[List[String]]` seems useless to me, as already provided. `scala> implicitly[Writes[List[String]]].writes(List("foo", "bar"))
res1: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = ["foo","bar"]`

Comment: Just filter the list before inserting it into MongoDB.

Comment: @cchantep - yes it is useless unless you need to remove empty values being inserted as mentioned. Strangely not an error but it just hangs.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov - I am filtering the list with the implicit value as shown above

Comment: Incidentally I now have the method as `def writes(list: List[String]): JsValue = Json.arr(list.filterNot(_.isEmpty).toIndexedSeq)` but this inserts an array as a value - meaning I have a nested array. Getting closer

Comment: `.map` the existing `Reads` rather than redefining from scratch

Comment: @cchantep - not sure what you mean or how that would be done

Comment: BTW if you get a hang then using `jstack` to get a stacktrace would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing specific versions or libraries you're using it's hard to give you an answer, but since you linked to play 2.6 documentation I'll assume that's what you're using there. The other assumption I'm going to make is that you're using reactive-mongo library. Whether or not you're using the play plugin for that library or not is the reason why I'm giving you two different answers here:

In that library, with no plugin, you'll have defined a [BSONDocumentReader](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/api/index.html#reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocumentReader) and a [BSONDocumentWriter](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/api/index.html#reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocumentWriter) for your case class. This might be auto-generated for you with macros or not, but regardless how you get it, these two classes have useful methods you can use to transform the reads/writes you have to another one. So, let's say I defined a reader and writer for you like this:

```
import reactivemongo.bson._

case class FormData(_id: Option[BSONObjectID], stadiumArr: Option[List[String]])

implicit val formDataReaderWriter = new BSONDocumentReader[FormData] with BSONDocumentWriter[FormData] {
    def read(bson: BSONDocument): FormData = {
        FormData(
            _id = bson.getAs[BSONObjectID]("_id"),
            stadiumArr = bson.getAs[List[String]]("stadiumArr").map(_.filterNot(_.isEmpty))
        )
    }
    def write(formData: FormData) = {
        BSONDocument(
            "_id" -> formData._id,
            "stadiumArr" -> formData.stadiumArr
        )
    }
}
```

Great you say, that works! You can see in the reads I went ahead and filtered out any empty strings. So even if it's in the data, it can be cleaned up. That's nice and all, but let's notice I didn't do the same for the writes. I did that so I can show you how to use a useful method called `afterWrite`. So pretend the reader/writer weren't the same class and were separate, then I can do this:

```
val initialWriter = new BSONDocumentWriter[FormData] {
    def write(formData: FormData) = {
        BSONDocument(
            "_id" -> formData._id,
            "stadiumArr" -> formData.stadiumArr
        )
    }
}

implicit val cleanWriter = initialWriter.afterWrite { bsonDocument =>
    val fixedField = bsonDocument.getAs[List[String]]("stadiumArr").map(_.filterNot(_.isEmpty))
    bsonDocument.remove("stadiumArr") ++ BSONDocument("stadiumArr" -> fixedField)
}
```

Note that `cleanWriter` is the implicit one, that means when the insert call on the collection happens, it will be the one chosen to be used.

---

Now, that's all a bunch of work, if you're using the plugin/module for play that lets you use `JSONCollection`s then you can get by with just defining play json [Reads](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.Reads) and [Writes](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.Writes). If you look at the documentation you'll see that the reads trait has a useful `map` function you can use to transform one Reads into another.

So, you'd have:

```
val jsonReads = Json.reads[FormData]
implicit val cleanReads = jsonReads.map(formData => formData.copy(stadiumArr = formData.stadiumArr.map(_.filterNot(_.isEmpty))))
```

And again, because only the clean Reads is implicit, the collection methods for mongo will use that.

---

NOW, all of that said, doing this at the database level is one thing, but really, I personally think you should be dealing with this at your Form level.

```
val form = Form(
    mapping(
      "_id" -> ignored(Option.empty[BSONObjectID]),
      "stadiumArr" -> optional(list(text)),
      ...
    )(FormData.apply)(FormData.unapply)
 )
```

Mainly because, surprise surprise, form has a way to deal with this. Specifically, the [mapping](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.data.Mapping) class itself. If you look there you'll find a `transform` method you can use to filter out empty values easily. Just call it on the mapping you need to modify, for example:

```
"stadiumArr" -> optional(
            list(text).transform(l => l.filter(_.nonEmpty), l => l.filter(_.nonEmpty))
        )
```

To explain a little more about this method, in case you're not used to reading the signatures in the scaladoc.

```
def
transform[B](f1: (T) ⇒ B, f2: (B) ⇒ T): Mapping[B]
```

says that by calling `transform` on some mapping of type `Mapping[T]` you can create a new mapping of type `Mapping[B]`.  In order to do this you must provide functions that convert from one to the other. So the code above causes the list mapping (`Mapping[List[String]]`) to become a `Mapping[List[String]]` (the type did not change here), but when it does so it removes any empty elements. If I break this code down a little it might be more clear:

```
def convertFromTtoB(list: List[String]): List[String] = list.filter(_.nonEmpty)
def convertFromBtoT(list: List[String]): List[String] = list.filter(_.nonEmpty)
...
list(text).transform(convertFromTtoB, convertFromBtoT)
```

You might wondering why you need to provide both, the reason is because when you call `Form.fill` and the form is populated with values, the second method will be called so that the data goes into the format the play form is expecting. This is more obvious if the type actually changes. For example, if you had a text area where people could enter CSV but you wanted to map it to a form model that had a proper List[String] you might do something like:

```
def convertFromTtoB(raw: String): List[String] = raw.split(",").filter(_.nonEmpty)
    def convertFromBtoT(list: List[String]): String = list.mkString(",")
    ...
    text.transform(convertFromTtoB, convertFromBtoT)
```

Note that when I've done this in the past sometimes I've had to write a separate method and just pass it in if I didn't want to fully specify all the types, but you should be able to work from here given the documentation and type signature for the transform method on mapping.

The reason I suggest doing this in the form binding is because the form/controller should be the one with the concern of dealing with your user data and cleaning things up I think. But you can always have multiple layers of cleaning and whatnot, it's not bad to be safe!

Comment: Yes sorry - I'm using the plugin/module for *play*. Some logical reasoning there; just can't get the transform right. Not sure I'm understanding exactly what is happening in those parameters.

Comment: @jesusg_forceHarris I've updated the answer around the transform method to explain some more

Comment: OK so I understand the function signature of *transform* and why (as you mention about filling forms) but I still can't get `"stadiumArr" -> optional(list(text).transform(l => l.filter(_.nonEmpty), l => l.filter(_.nonEmpty)))` to work. IntelliJ gives me this warning on the 2nd parameter: ***`Type mismatch: expected: (NotInferedB) => List[String], actual: (Nothing) => Any`***

Comment: I have just however noticed that this does work when put into methods as you mentioned. Strange but I think this solution is probably the most economic performance-wise

Answer (score 0):

I've gone for this (which always seems obvious when it's written and tested):

```
    implicit val arrayWrite: Writes[List[String]] = new Writes[List[String]] {
      def writes(list: List[String]): JsValue = Json.toJson(list.filterNot(_.isEmpty).toIndexedSeq)
    }
```

But I would be interested to know how to

> .map the existing Reads rather than redefining from scratch

as @cchantep suggests

Comment: RE: cchantep's suggestions, what are you using for reading/writing to mongo? reactive mongo BSON or reactive mongo play module/plugin? I can write something up for you in regards to mapping an existing reads if you can tell me some more info about which library you're using